# Use Quick Responses with Google Voice

Tags: google-voice, quick-responses

One of the most useful features introduced in Ice Cream Sandwich is "Quick Responses": the ability to send a default SMS message to the caller. "Can't talk now. Will call you back." etc.

However, I'm 100% Google Voice. I only ever give out my GV number, and I don't want to broadcast my actual cell phone number by using a Quick Response.

Is there a way to use them with Google Voice?

Comment: [Android 4.3 comes with a new service intent filter: "ACTION_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE"](http://www.androidcentral.com/new-android-43-features-third-party-sms-apps-quick-replies-and-notification-listener). Hopefully Google Voice will implement this _tout de suite_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is apparently not currently possible.

I'm not the only person with this desire. There's an open issue at Google ([Issue 23176](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=23176)).

In one of my searches, I found someone who says they looked into the code for the Phone app, and found that it's calling the Messaging app directly without allowing the Messaging Intent, which is what would prompt me to choose the Messaging app versus Google Voice to send the message.

The app suggested by [dymutaos](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35386/267) looked somewhat promising, but I am concerned about its security.

So, unfortunately, this very useful feature is currently useless to me. I hope they fix it in the not-too-distant future.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdrtools.apps.gvintegration) (they have a limited [free version](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mdrtools.apps.gvintegration.free)). It is supposed to integrate Google Voice into the native messenger, so it may also work with the Quick Responses, depending on how Android actually implements them.

Comment: Possibly, but there are a number of troubling reviews there in the Play Store.

Comment: Yeah, I saw those as well, but at least they have a free version you could install to test it out. Maybe it will work for you? If not, I can delete my answer.

Comment: Except I saw one review say that they couldn't remove the integration. I'm still mulling it over; don't delete your answer.

Comment: Nah, I'm not going for that. It's requiring me to put in my account and password rather than using the built in Google Authentication. I'm not taking a chance.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have Google Voice setup, you could try simply going to Settings>Apps>All Apps> MMS.apk - & Clear Defaults.

Then, when you select a quick response, it should prompt you to use GVoice, instead.

Comment: Don't have "MMS.apk" listed in my All Apps list. I assume you mean "Messaging". "Clear defaults" is grayed out, though.

Answer (score 0):

Not yet, apparently there are hooks in the code called intents that are responsible for asking which app you would like certain tasks to be performed by. The quick responses did not have intents. They are there as of Android 4.3, but Google Voice has yet to update with a register for that hook.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56090

Answer (score -1):

Google voice has the following option which sounds like it could do what you want, but only when texting to another GV number. This is according to the "learn more" text on the site; I haven't experimented to find its real capabilities:

```
- Caller ID (outgoing)   When I text a Google Voice number from one of my
  forwarding phones:
     - Don't change anything
     - Display my Google Voice number
```

Comment: That's not what that's about. That means that if I text someone's Google Voice number from my phone, GV should recognize that my phone is registered in GV and can use my number instead. Quick Responses isn't going through Google Voice; it's phone to phone.